# Find value of f(2013)?

Tags: functions, dynamic-programming

Given a function $f(x)$ such that: $f(1) + f(2) + f(3)+\cdots+f(n) = n^2f(n)$

Find the value of $f(2013)$. It is given that $f(1) = 2014$.

I tried attempting the question as a bottom-up DP, but soon realized the numbers are too irregular and large to deal with in a mechanical fashion.

Comment: It would probably be easiest to do this by just writing something in Python, Matlab, etc. to compute the values. Or do you need to compute it by hand?

Comment: Is the right hand side $n^2$? Or is it $n^2 \cdot f(n)$?

Comment: This question was asked in a mathematics contest and is supposed to be done with a pen and paper,and not a computer.

Comment: @JohnHughes The RHS is $n^2$ multiplied by $f(n)$.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, which contest was this?

Comment: @IlmariKaronen It was some random inter-school contest in Delhi, India.

Answer (score 7):

Rule of thumb: if the current year shows up in a problem, it is probably a red herring.

Second rule of thumb: looking for a pattern will help you decide what to prove.

$$f(1) + f(2) = 4 f(2) \implies f(2) = \frac{f(1)}{3}$$ $$f(1) + \frac{f(1)}{3} + f(3) = 9 f(3) \implies f(3) = \frac{f(1)}{6}$$ $$f(1) + \frac{f(1)}{3} + \frac{f(1)}{6} + f(4) = 16 f(4) \implies   f(4) = \frac{f(1)}{10}$$
$$f(1) + \frac{f(1)}{3} + \frac{f(1)}{6} + \frac{f(1)}{10} + f(5) = 25 f(5)  \implies f(5) = \frac{f(1)}{15}$$

From here you should be able to make an educated guess about the value of $f(2013)$ and a formal proof should not be hard to write.

Answer (score 5):

$$n^2f(n)-(n-1)^2f(n-1)=f(n)\\(n^2-1)f(n)=(n-1)^2f(n-1)\\f(n)=\frac{(n-1)}{n+1}f(n-1)=\frac{n-1}{n+1}\cdot\frac{n-2}{n}f(n-2)=\cdots=\frac{(n-1)!}{(n+1)\cdot n\cdots4\cdot3}f(1)=\frac{2}{n(n+1)}f(1)\\f(2013)=\frac{2}{2013\cdot 2014}\cdot2014=\frac{2}{2013}$$

Comment: The denominator at the end of the third line is a factor of $2$ too big.  There are the same number of multiplicands in the numerator and denominator, so if you're counting down from $(n+1)$, $(n-1)$ times, the smallest one will be $3$.

Comment: @John Thanks,corrected.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**

Show using induction that $$f(n)=\frac{1}{1+2+\cdots +n}f(1)=\frac{2}{n(n+1)}f(1).$$

Answer (score 1):

Set $n=m,m+1$ one by one to find $f(m+1)$ in terms of $f(m)$

$$\sum_{r=1}^{m-1}f(r)=(m^2-1)f(m)$$

$$\{(m+1)^2-1\}f(m+1)=\sum_{r=1}^{m}f(r)=\sum_{r=1}^{m-1}f(r)+f(m)=(m^2-1)f(m)+f(m)$$

$$\iff m(m+2)f(m+1)=m^2f(m)\iff f(m+1)=\frac m{m+2}f(m)$$ for $m>0$

Answer (score 1):

Calculating a few of the first $n$ by hand reveals a pattern:

$$f(n) = \frac{f(1)}{T_n},$$

where $T_n$ is the $n$th triangular number.

Proof by induction:

The relationship holds for $n=1$ since $T_1 = 1.$

We assume that

$$f(x) = \sum_{k=1}^n f(k) = \frac{2}{n(n+1)} f(1).$$

This implies that

$$\frac{2}{n(n+1)} f(1) = n^2 f(n).$$

Then,

$$f(x+1) = \sum_{k=1}^{n+1} f(k) = n^2 f(n) + f(n+1) = (n+1)^2 f(n+1),$$

and

$$f(n+1) = \frac{n}{n+2}f(n) = \frac{2f(1)}{n(n+1)}\frac{n}{n+2} = \frac{2f(1)}{(n+1)(n+2)} = \frac{f(1)}{T_{n+1}}.$$

To answer the question, then,

$$f(2013) = \frac{2 \cdot 2014}{2013 \cdot 2014} = \frac{2}{2013}.$$